# LDAP error code 49: what do the 'v' codes mean?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, error-code

The error I'm getting is as below:

> [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1

I've found a whole ream of information on what the various parts of this mean, including [a list of LDAP error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024909/2294676), which covers the **52e** code.

I can't find any information at all on what the **v1db1** means. I've found examples where various 'v' codes are combined with various AD-specific error codes, e.g.:

- [v893](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631)
- [vece](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/474abb8f-cfc6-4cac-af79-c3e80e80291f/ldap-authentication-error-ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid0c090334-comment?forum=winserverDS)
- v1db1
- [v1172](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2672125/2294676)

Does anyone know what these 'v-' codes are and what they mean?

Comment: v1 suggests a version, and db suggests a database number.

Comment: @EJP thanks but that doesn't fit with the other v-codes or the sheer consistency of these four codes appearing. One would expect more diversity if it were simply version numbers.